# Persistent Installation to USB Stick

Tags: live-usb

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do I install Ubuntu to a USB key?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/16988/how-do-i-install-ubuntu-to-a-usb-key)

I want to carry around a persistent installation of Ubuntu on a USB stick with all my favourite bits of software. What's the simplest way to do this?

Comment: I know it's weird to dupe to a newer question, but the method in the above question works very well.